# Sharing keystore between multiple apps

Tags: android, keystore

I am developing an SDK/API that will be used by apps not written by me.

I want my code to generate a private key once and store it on the device.

This key should be unique per device, I don't mind it being erased on factory reset, and I don't need to extract it from the device.

Sounds an ideal case for the KeyStore (preferably with a StrongBox).

I do want, though, different apps to use the same key to sign (or ask my API to do so)

I could not answer two concerns:

- If my API is a library linked (statically) into the app, different apps using my code wouldn't be able to use the key, because the keystore requires
- If I package my API as a separate android app, and have the other apps use it using Intents, I'll have to have the user install it manually, because as far as I could tell, Android/Play does not allow for dependencies between apps.

What is the most graceful way to resolve this situation?

Comment: something like generating a random alphanumeric string of 32 bit would help?

Comment: @Sam. how would that help?